# Getting the sleep/suspend/hibernate status from the CLI on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

How can I confirm I have successfully turned off sleep and hibernate mode on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine from the CLI?

I only have access to the machine via SSH, so I have no GUI.

I ran the following:

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`

Is there a way to get the sleep/suspend/hibernate settings from the CLI?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the way is as shown below:

```
sudo systemctl status sleep.target
sudo systemctl status suspend.target
sudo systemctl status hibernate.target
sudo systemctl status hybrid-sleep.target
```

Information:

```
man systemd.special 7
```

Comment: I think `hibride-sleep` should be spelled `hybrid-sleep`

Comment: @WInEunuuchs2Unix yes I believe so :)